# When does the TS compiler output EMCAScript Private Fields using WeakMaps?

Tags: typescript, private-members

I'm aware that the TypeScript compiler can use a workaround via [`WeakMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/WeakMap) to "polyfill" [ECMAScript Private class fields](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Private_class_fields), but when does/doesn't it do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the official documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#caveats), the TypeScript compiler uses `WeakMap`s when [the target output](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#target) is configured to ES2021 or less, and otherwise outputs ECMAScript private class fields.